# Swift 2 remove object from array with contains string have

Tags: arrays, swift, string, swift2

I have string array in Swift 2:

```
var myList              : [String] = []
```

And I have dynamic strings inside and I explode them with `*` character myList examples:

```
   print(myList[0])  output = 2018-04-05*type2*namea
   print(myList[1])  output = 2018-04-05*type2*nameb
   print(myList[2])  output = 2018-04-05*type3*nameb
   print(myList[3])  output = 2018-04-06*type3*named
```

I want to delete objects have **type3** ones in myList:

**IF** IN **same date** AND **same name** AND have **type2** ones

Must be my strings like that:

```
   print(myList[0])  output = 2018-04-05*type2*namea
   print(myList[1])  output = 2018-04-05*type2*nameb
   print(myList[2])  output = 2018-04-06*type3*named
```

This item below must be deleted:

```
   print(myList[2])  output = 2018-04-05*type3*nameb
```

I want to delete type3 ones in myList if before have type2 with same date and same name basically.

Explain:

`2018-04-05*type2*nameb` and `2018-04-05*type3*nameb`, have **same date and same name** but `2018-04-05*type3*nameb` before have **type2**(2018-04-05*type2*nameb) ? so 2018-04-05*type3*nameb line must be **delete**

How can I do it?

Comment: I can't make any sense out of your post.

Comment: @DuncanC :) yeah it is complex

Comment: @DuncanC I want to delete type3 ones in myList if before have type2 with same date and same name basicly

Comment: @DuncanC so you can see there which ones will be delete i wrote

Comment: Your type2 items have different names

Comment: @W.K.S  2018-04-05*type2*nameb and  2018-04-05*type3*nameb , have same date and same name but  2018-04-05*type3*nameb before have type2 ? so   2018-04-05*type3*nameb line must be delete

Comment: Also, can you please provide a bit more context to your problem. I somewhat feel you're making the problem more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @W.K.S i added example explain in my question bottom

Comment: It's not that the problem is complex, it's that your description of it is indecipherable.

Comment: Are you saying you want to delete entries that contain "type3", where the entry just before it is "type2", and where both the "type3" entry and the preceding "type2" entry have the same date? And are these strings always in exactly the same format, with the exact same number of characters?

Answer (score 3):

This playground code will do what you want:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

let myList = ["2018-04-05*type2*namea",
              "2018-04-05*type2*nameb",
              "2018-04-05*type3*nameb",
              "2018-04-06*type3*named"]

//Define a class that lets us map from a string to a date, type, and name string
class ListEntry {
    let fullString: String

    //define lazy vars for all the substrings
    lazy var subStrings: [Substring] = fullString.split(separator: "*")
    lazy var dateString = subStrings[0]
    lazy var typeString = subStrings[1]
    lazy var nameString = subStrings[2]

    //Create a failable initializer that takes a full string as input 
    //and tries to break it into exactly 3 substrings
    //using the "*" sparator
    init?(fullString: String) {
        self.fullString = fullString
        if subStrings.count != 3 { return nil }
    }
}

print("---Input:---")
myList.forEach { print($0) }
print("------------")

//Map our array of strings to an array of ListEntry objects
let items = myList.compactMap { ListEntry(fullString: $0) }

//Create an output array
var  output: [String] = []

//Loop through each item in the array of ListEntry objects, getting an index for each
for (index,item) in items.enumerated() {

    //If this is the first item, or it dosn't have  type == "type3", add it to the output
    guard index > 0,
        item.typeString == "type3" else {
            print("Adding item", item.fullString)
            output.append(item.fullString)
            continue
    }
    let previous = items[index-1]

    /*
     Add this item if
        -the previous type isn't "type2"
        -the previous item's date doesn't match this one
        -the previous item's name doesn't match this one
     */
    guard previous.typeString == "type2",
        item.dateString == previous.dateString,
        item.nameString == previous.nameString else {
            print("Adding item", item.fullString)
            output.append(item.fullString)
            continue
    }
    print("Skipping item ", item.fullString)
}
print("\n---Output:---")
output.forEach { print($0) }
```

The output of the code above is:

```
---Input:---
2018-04-05*type2*namea
2018-04-05*type2*nameb
2018-04-05*type3*nameb
2018-04-06*type3*named
------------
Adding item 2018-04-05*type2*namea
Adding item 2018-04-05*type2*nameb
Skipping item  2018-04-05*type3*nameb
Adding item 2018-04-06*type3*named

---Output:---
2018-04-05*type2*namea
2018-04-05*type2*nameb
2018-04-06*type3*named
```

Comment: i need to use this with swift 2

Comment: Swift 2?! Why? That is 2 major language versions out of date.

Comment: C with latest swift thats do easy but with swift 2 dont work. my project in swift 2.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start you off with a simple (albeit hack-ish) approach:

```
let myList = ["2018-04-05*type2*namea", "2018-04-05*type2*nameb", "2018-04-05*type3*nameb", "2018-04-06*type3*named"]
```

Define the function:

```
func swapLastTwoComps(_ s: String) -> String {
    let parts = s.split(separator: "*")
    return [parts[0], parts[2], parts[1]].joined(separator: "*")
}
```

Now if you do

```
let myListS = myList.map {swapLastTwoComps($0)}.sorted()
```

you get

```
["2018-04-05*namea*type2", "2018-04-05*nameb*type2", "2018-04-05*nameb*type3", "2018-04-06*named*type3"]
```

i.e. the sort has left strings to be removed adjacent and to the right of their equivalent, so now you can easily loop through the array and remove the strings you want (because you only need to compare each String's prefix with the String immediately to its left to determine whether it should be removed).

Once you've done that, map `swapLastTwoComps` over the final array again to restore the strings to their previous format.