# Swift 2 String Array remove Spesific Index Error

Tags: arrays, swift, string, swift2

I have String Array;

```
var students                      = [String]()
```

and my students array output :

```
students[0]:102----3----
students[1]:102-2018.07.24-4--6---
students[2]:103--5--4--
students[3]:34-2018.07.24---3-4--6--
students[4]:34--6---5----4--
```

I want to remove **students[0]** so students[1] same id with students[0] and students[0] dont have date.

I want to remove **students[4]** so students[3] same id with students[4] and students[4] dont have date.

In Swift 2 how can i do it ?

Must be output

```
students[0]:102-2018.07.24-4--6---
students[1]:103--5--4--
students[2]:34-2018.07.24---3-4--6--
```

My test codes;

```
var count = 0
for mystudents in self.students {                                      
    let explode1 = "\(mystudents)".componentsSeparatedByString("-")
    let explode2 = "\(mystudents)".componentsSeparatedByString("-")                                     

    if  (explode1[0] == explode2[0]) { // HERE if equal same ids                                       
        if (explode1[1] == "" || explode2[1] == ""]){                     
           self.students.removeAtIndex(count++) // HERE gives fatal error: Index out of range
        }                                        
    }                                      
}
```

And

i didnt fix tihs about 5 days , who will fix this i will give **500 reps** after 2 days with bounty

Comment: what final result you want ?

Comment: Is this related to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/50030577/1187415? Or are you simply looking for `remove(at: index)` ?

Comment: I added must be output in question bottom

Comment: I propose you use Swift 4 and and Google what is data structure.

Comment: @RajuyourPepe my project in swift 2 :(

Comment: Swift 2 is dead. You are highly encouraged to update.

Comment: @vadian yeah i know but project big , have any idea for this fix ?

Comment: In Swift 3+ it's `.dropLast().dropFrist()` I don't know if the functions are available in Swift 2. Otherwise get the index of the last item and remove that, then remove the first.

Comment: @vadian droplast and dropfirst dont need so i think must be explode in each string and something like if same id and date == "" remove index ..

Comment: @vadian i added my test codes gives that line : fatal error: Index out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am suggesting the below solution on the understanding that you want to remove an object that has only id and it matches with other object that has same id and date. If my understanding is wrong, please let me know,

```
    let students = ["102----3----",
                    "103--5--4--",
                    "102-2018.07.24-4--6---",
                    "34-2018.07.24---3-4--6--",
                    "34--6---5----4--"]

    let filtered = students.filter { (student) -> Bool in
        let id = student.characters.split{$0 == "-"}.map({ String($0) })
        let exists = students.filter({ (other) -> Bool in
            if student == other {
                return false
            }
            let otherId = other.characters.split{$0 == "-"}.map({String($0) }).first!
            return id.first! == otherId
        }).first
        if exists != nil, id.count > 1 {
            return id[1].characters.filter({ $0 == "."}).count == 2
        }
        return true
    }
    print(filtered)
```

**Output:**

```
["103--5--4--", "102-2018.07.24-4--6---", "34-2018.07.24---3-4--6--"]
```

Comment: @Kamran dude this is dynamic datas, must be if have same ids and delete only date empty one

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper I updated the answer. Can you look at it?

Comment: @Kamran im looking

Comment: @dude 2 line have split ones gives: error : Value of type 'String' has no member 'split'

Comment: I think you have to change `split` to `componentsSeparatedByString("-")`

Comment: @kamran i did it and output = same , dont do any change

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper I updated the splitting. Please try now.

Comment: @Kamran okay dude im looking

Comment: @Kamran dude i integrated that codes inside my project but in my project array id not 0th, id in 4th and date 9 th so firsts dont work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176651/discussion-between-swiftdeveloper-and-kamran).

Comment: @Kamran dude i integareted my codes like question id is [0] and date [1] now , but same result

Comment: @Kamran dont chek your codes if same ids and date = ""

Comment: @Kamran my real data : let students = ["102--Z--01--102-102-C-x-01------------------------------",
                        "103--M--01--103-103-D-x-01------------------------------",
                        "102-2018.07.24-K--01--102-102-F-x-01-2018.07.24------",
                        "34-2018.07.24-Z--01--34-34-G-x-01-2018.07.24------",
                        "34--Z--01--34-34-M-x-01------------------------------"]

Comment: @Kamran i changed my data same of example , first object id, and second is date

Comment: @Kamran DUDE if you look only first id, and first date i think will works. Only first id and first date same !

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper Please check now. I updated the answer. But i still have doubts about the input. If the input is same as you put in the answer above then you will get the correct output. But if you still have some different input then it might not work as expected.

Comment: @Kamran looking good im integrating it into my project , takes times after i will turn you if ok. i will give you 500 REPS man thank you. looking good. I will turn

Comment: that codes is dont work with [4], and [9] in my project , i changed them real objects, but dont sad i will give you 150 reps.